# Trying to get an MS Access query the hours in one day

Tags: vba, ms-access, datediff

I have three 5 columns in my query:

- Count(ID)
- Min(Date)
- Max(Date)
- Hours: DateDiff("h",Min([Date]),Max([Date]))
- UPH: Count([ID])/[Hours]

I want the query to return the count per day, for example:

```
Count(ID) |       Min(Date)             |       Max(Date)           | Hours  |  UPH
    30    |   9/29/2020 11:00:00 AM     |   9/29/2020 11:00:00 PM   |  12    |  2.5
```

I have tried the following code but had no luck

```
Between #9/29/2020 12:00:01 AM# And #9/29/2020 11:59:59 PM#
```

Seems like I can only get it to run within a day range, not an hourly range.

Comment: Would probably need to see your whole query, as it depends on how you are using your WHERE and your GROUP BY - fwiw: [Date] is a really bad name for a field, since it's a key word. Something like OrderDate would be better - something that describes what kind of date it is.

Comment: Yes sorry, i just used [Date] on here for simplicity. 
I did figure it out just now though , I needed to add a WHERE clause "WHERE (((audits.date_entered) Between #9/29/2020# And #9/30/2020#))" . Thank you for the tip ! it was you mentioning the WHERE clause that instantly made it click !